# Searching for files in a Listbox

Tags: c#

I am trying to have an application generate file names then search to see if the files exist. The current issue is, the loop only ever finds the last 2 files on the list.

In my below example screenshots, you can see that if I reorder the files, it still only finds the last 2.

Just for the heck of it, I changed the Listbox to a Textbox to try and loop through, and that gave the same results. Current code is using Listboxes again.

Lastly, the "Store Numbers" box is a textbox that the user fills out. The rest are listboxes.

[image]
[image]

```
private void findButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string dirPath = @"cashFiles\";
            foreach (object file in outputBox.Items) 
            {
                // Search 1
                if (File.Exists(dirPath + "1\\" + file.ToString()))
                {
                    resultBox.Items.Add("Found " + dirPath + @"1\" + file);
                    foundfileBox.Items.Add(dirPath + @"1\" + file);
                }
                else
                {
                    resultBox.Items.Add("Not Found " + dirPath + @"1\" + file);
                }
            }
        }



 private void generateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var textLines = storeNumbers.Text.Split('\n');
            foreach (var line in textLines)
            {
                outputBox.Items.Add("c" + line + datebox.Text + "0.dat");
                outputBox.Items.Add("c" + line + datebox.Text + "1.dat");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe the files don't exist? Where is the code that creates them?

Comment: nice app. is there link to download it and test?

Comment: @GuyVdN I just created the files by hand for testing and they exist for sure. As you can see from the screenshots, if I change the order, it finds the bottom ones every time.

Comment: Side note: recommended to use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-6.0) to build the paths.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JohnnyMopp, going to update to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't simply split at any found `\n` character. That's the problem.

On Windows, line breaks are typically encoded as `\r\n`.

So, as an example, in your Store Numbers textbox you have the string `"0047\r\n0049"`.

Doing a `\n` split will result in the two strings `"0047\r"` and `"0049"`. Note that the first string contains the `\r` character.

Thus, all file names generated from this first string also contain the `\r` character. Obviously, there are no files in your *cashFiles* directory that possess such an `\r` character.

You can't see these `\r` characters in your GUI, because all those controls do not visibly render the character `\r`. But when you debug your code and ***carefully*** inspect the generated file names character-by-character in the debugger, you'll notice the `\r` in some of the generated file names.

There are different ways of how you could split the string with the Store Numbers correctly regardless of whether it contains Windows-style or Unix/Linux-style line breaks. One simple way is to utilize `Environment.NewLine`, which provides the character sequence that is used for line breaks by the underlying operating system.

```
var textLines = storeNumbers.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine);
```

This relies on the fact that line breaks typed into GUI controls are normally governed by the underlying operating system.

If for any reason the line break character sequences in the string do not match with the line break character sequence as used by the underlying operating system, another relatively simple approach could be:

```
var textLines = storeNumbers.Text.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Great catch, missed that. You can also use  [Environment.NewLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=net-6.0) instead of "\r\n"

Comment: @GuyVdN, true :-)
Edit coming...

Comment: That was it! Man, I wasn't even troubleshooting in that section, I was convinced my issue was in the looping method. Thank you so much for your time and information.